# how can i modify language model before applying patterns

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I have this code :

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher,PhraseMatcher
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab,validate=True)
patterns = [
    [{'POS': 'QUALIF'}, {'POS': 'CCONJ'}, {'POS': 'ADJ'}, {'POS': 'NOUN'}],
]
matcher.add("process_1", None, *patterns)

texts= ["it is a beautiful and big apple"]
for text in texts:
  doc = nlp(text)
  matches = matcher(doc)
  for _, start, end in matches:
      print(doc[start:end].text)
```

So, I want to modify for example the POS of `"beautiful"` from `"ADJ"`  to `"QUALIF"` just before applying patterns matchers (as you know beautiful in spacy language model is `"ADJ"` but me I want to modify it to `"QUALIF"` just before applying the matcher.
Help please.

Comment: This is somehwat unclear: what is the final goal? If you want to extract both patterns with qualifier and adjective, why not simply add the second pattern?

Comment: because in input , i have a text like : 
text= "it_PRON is_AUX a_DET beautiful_QUALIF and_CCONJ big_ADJ apple_NOUN"  (my text is define like word_POS ...) 
and i want to apply patterns matcher on this text and taking the POS associate with each word

Comment: So why not use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65398500/3832970)?